# When is k^k = poly(n)?

Tags: computational-complexity

When does $k^k = \mathrm{poly}(n)$?

More specifically, does
$$ k^k = \mathrm{poly}(n) \impliedby k = \mathcal O\left( \frac{\log n}{\log \log n} \right) $$
hold? I saw that
$$ k! = \mathrm{poly}(n) \impliedby k = \mathcal O \left( \frac{\log n}{\log \log n} \right) $$
holds, though struggle to prove that either.

Edit: I should have been more clear that $k$ depends on $n$. The problem came up in the study of randomised algorithms on graphs, where $k$ is path size and $n$ is the number of vertices. It came up in a discussion on cases for an algorithm to be RP (with little detail on these "trivialities" I do not get).

Comment: Assuming $poly(n)$ represents the class of all polynomials in $n$ then 
$k^k$ is a constant "from $poly(n)$ point of view" namely : $k^k = 0\cdot n^m + 0\cdot n^{m-1} + ... + 0\cdot n + k^k$ thus $k^k \in poly(n)$.

Comment: We have that if $k=\log(n)$ then $k^k=n^{\log(\log(n))}$ for large $n$ for example $n=10^{100000000}$ we have that $\log(\log(n))\approx 19.25$ hence you can compare it to $n^{20}$ for example.This is just practical though,not mathematical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
k \leq C \, \frac{\log n}{\log\log n}
$$
where $C \geq 2$ is an arbitrary constant. Then, for large enough $n > e^e$,
\begin{align*}
  k^k &= e^{k\log k} \leq \exp\left( \frac{C\log n}{\log\log n} \times \log\left( \frac{C\log n}{\log \log n} \right)  \right) \\
  &\leq \exp\left( \frac{C\log n}{\log\log n} \times \log (C\log n) \right) \\
  &\leq \exp\left( \frac{C\log n}{\log\log n} \times C \log \log n \right) \\
  &= \exp \left( C^2 \log n \right) \\
  &= n^{C^2} = \mathrm{poly}(n)
\end{align*}
as required.